# Regex is not accepting space in between digits

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

Using this regex: `(.*)(EB([\s]{0,})[0-9]{7})` to remove white spaces and able to read 7 digits after `EB` but its not accepting space between digits.

Currently it's passing value with space after `EB` and not accepting space in b/w 7 digits.

Input string: `EB 67645 89`

Using `value.replaceAll("\s","");` in code.

Comment: could you enumerate what is the input string, what is the expected behaviour and what is the expected output? also format the code

Comment: We need to assign payment for EB6764589 even if theres a space after 5. Currently above regex is only accepting space after EB and not b/w digits. I need to make regex accept space in b/w digits. @GastónSchabas

Comment: You mention *Using `value.replaceAll("\s","");` in code*. Does this work? I guess the syntax would be `value.replaceAll(new RegExp("\\s+","g"), '')` but `value.replace(/\s+/g, "")` is shorter and does the same. You can combine it with `match` and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 7 digits like this demo at tio.run: [`value.replace(/\s+/g,"").match(/EB(\d{7})/)[1]`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pye1RKEsMac0VcFWQd3VScHM3MzEVMHCUp2LKzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dA6xEryi1ICcxOVVDP6ZYWz9dR0lJUy83sSQ5Q0Pf1UkjJqXavFZTXzPaMFbz/38A)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex, it should help to solve your problem:

```
(.*)(EB)\s*(\d\s*){7}
```

By the way you can use regex101 to play with regex, it's very useful environment when you're working with regexps.

Comment: What about [0,9] before {7} and whats significance of {0,}.

Comment: Currently its accepting only one space, we need to make it accept multiple spaces as well. Earlier its was accepting multiple spaces after EB.

Comment: Got you, you meant multiple spaces between words then use this one https://regex101.com/r/lZ2zAH/1

Comment: Thanks Anton. I have one doubt why its not working with (.*)(EB)\s*(\d\s*)[0-9]{7}, if i add [0,9]

Comment: Why do you need [0,9] at whole? This part (\d\s*){7} means you will have subsequence of any digit with or without whitespaces 7 times. Basically if you want to say any digit - you can use \d.

Answer (score 1):

To match the example string you don't need the capture groups, you can match 7 times a digit preceded by optional whitespace chars (note that it can also match newlines).

Then you can remove the whitespace chars from this match using replaceAll:

```
\bEB(?:\s*\d){7}\b
```

In Java

```
String regex = "\\bEB(?:\\s*\\d){7}\\b";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULfRL6/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the space will only ever appear after the 5th digit, then the following pattern will work.

```
EB\s(?:\d{7}|\d{5}\s\d\d)
```

You can use a literal space, also.

```
EB (?:\d{7}|\d{5} \d\d)
```